# Java - Thymeleaf - HTML: Linebreak <br/> does not work?

Tags: html, containers, line-breaks

I am using IntelliJ and Spring Boot and Thymeleaf for a database visualisation project. The following HTML-Template is for the view of one gene:

gene.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Gene</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="content/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!--import header-->
<header th:include="header"></header>

    <div id="main">
        <!--GeneID as page heading -->
        <h2 th:text="'Gene: '+${identifier}" style="text-align: center"></h2>
        <!--Gene description -->
        <p th:text="${description}" style="text-align: center"></p>
        <br/>
        <!-- Sequence -->
        <h3 th:text="'Sequence:'"></h3>
        <!-- For each char in sequence-->
        <th:block th:each="char:${sequence}">
            <!-- Print the char. Color encoding done by main.css -->
            <div th:class="${'gene ' + char}" th:text="${char}"></div>
        </th:block>

        <!--Protein encoded by gene -->
        <h3 th:text="'Protein:'"></h3>
        <a th:href="${'protein?id='+protein}" th:text="${protein}"></a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my later view, I have a problem. 
[image]

I want the "Protein: Q6GZX4" to be in one line below the sequence. Yet I could not achieve it with `<br/>`or anything else.

What am I missing?
Thanks for your time and effort :)

Comment: Im not sure you could try with css if that's not working `p.clear {
  clear: both;
}`

Comment: worked with clear:both (put protein part in container and made a css-class). Protein now is below the sequence and <br/> works within the container

Answer (score 0):

Based on @manfromnowhere:

Change gene.html to:

```
[...]
   <!--Protein encoded by gene -->
        <div class="breaker">
            <br/>
        <h3 style="display:inline-block;" th:text="'Protein:'"></h3>
        <a th:href="${'protein?id='+protein}" th:text="${protein}"></a>
        </div>
```

breaker-class in main.css:

```
div.breaker{
  clear:both;
}
```

Output: 
[image]